# The IIS Express applicationHost.config file contains invalid entries

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am getting this error while creating a new web application project after a fresh install of VS2019.

Please see the details: The IIS Express applicationHost.config file contains invalid entries
and must be corrected before you can open project xxxxx'

xxxx is for what it shows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbR6P.png)at the end'

Comment: Sounds like your .NET Framework 4.x installation is corrupt. You must fix that first.

Comment: @LexLi Can you guide me on how I can fix that? Is that something I need to download? Because I searched for it and didn't find anything helpful. I gotta say I may be looked for it in the wrong place.

Comment: I wonder why your search didn't include this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2698555/microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-is-available

Comment: @LexLi I actually looked at that I didn't include it in the question part tho. Anyway, the last resort was the laptop needed a factory reset. Clean slate everything. Because various MS apps started failing. VS2019/17, SSMS, etc..

Comment: You might post your answer and accept it. As .NET Framework is used by various Microsoft products, corruption can impact quite a lot of them. Not a surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for my own problem as it escalated to crashing various MS apps like  Visual Studio, SSMS, etc.. – that are calling the .Net framework; therefore, my last resort was the laptop needed a factory reset. Clean slate everything.